# REPLACE INTO causes Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to copy data from one column to another column inside a different table using this query

```
REPLACE INTO am_finder_value (dropdown_id, name) SELECT 6, ukyear FROM am_finder_models WHERE ukyear IS NOT NULL AND ukyear <>'';
```

am_finder_models

```
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| model_id   | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| modelname  | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ukyear     | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| euroyear   | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| chassis_id | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

am_finder_value

```
+-------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| value_id    | int(10) unsigned      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| parent_id   | int(10) unsigned      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| dropdown_id | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| name        | varchar(255)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I keep getting

```
Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

I've increased the timeout to 300

```
| Variable_name            | Value |
+--------------------------+-------+
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout | 300   |
+--------------------------+-------+
```

Is there a better more efficient way to copy the data across?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

in `phpmyadmin` 
This will display the threads with there ids and execution time
so you can kill the threads that are taking too much time to execute